# Confused by how to write OO Javascript to implement simple class pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I am totally befuddled by OO Javascript so I cannot even recognize the same question.

I am trying to write the Javascript class that will execute the following common type of pattern:

```
var User=require('./models').User();

User.findUserById('1', function(err, user) {console.log(user)});


var newUser            = new User();

// set the user's local credentials
newUser.local.email    = 'simon@infoqual.net';
newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash('hello');

// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    console.log(newUser); //returns undefined for the attributes set above
    return newUser;
});
```

At present, none of my getter attributes make it to my inner save function. Here is the code for the whole class I am writing.

```
exports.User = User;

function User() {
    var user_uuid, local_email, local_password, user=this;

    function generateHash(password) {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    }

    function validPassword(password, password_compare) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, password_compare);
    }

    function findUserByEmail(email, callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE local_email=$1 LIMIT 1", [email], function (error, result) {
            //var user = this.User;
            if (!error) {
                if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                    local_email = result.rows[0].email;
                    user_uuid = result.rows[0].user_uuid;

                    //load rest of user obj
                    callback(error, user_uuid);
                }


            }
            callback(error, null);

        });


    }

    function findUserById(id, callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uuid='' || $1 LIMIT 1", [id], function (error, result) {
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                //update
                user_uuid = result.rows[0].user_uuid;
                local_email = result.rows[0].local_email;
                local_password = result.rows[0].local_password;
                callback(null, user_uuid);
            } else {
                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    function save(callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uuid='' || $1", [user_uuid], function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw error;
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                //update
                conn.query("UPDATE users SET local_email=$1, local_password=$2 WHERE user_uuid=$3", [local_email, local_password, user_uuid], function (error, result) {
                    if (error) throw error;

                    callback(error);
                })
            } else {
                //insert
                conn.query("INSERT INTO users (user_uuid, local_email, local_password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [require('node-uuid').v1(), local_email, local_password], function (error, result) {
                    if (error) throw error;

                    callback(error);
                })
            }
        })
    }

    return {
        user_uuid: user_uuid,

        local: {
            email: local_email,
            password: local_password
        },
        facebook: {
            id: null,
            token: null,
            email: null,
            name: null
        },
        twitter: {
            id: null,
            token: null,
            displayName: null,
            username: null
        },
        google: {
            id: null,
            token: null,
            email: null,
            name: null
        },
        generateHash: generateHash,
        validPassword: validPassword,
        findUserByEmail: findUserByEmail,
        findUserById: findUserById,
        save: save

    }
};
```

Why does my inner .save function not have access to the local_email and local_password variables that were set in the constructor?

Comment: `return newUser` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suspect the primary issue is `local_email` and `local_password` are storing strings, and you can't pass strings by reference. When you change the value of local.email, it isn't changing the value of local_email. Though, what' your claiming about the console.log showing undefined values doesn't make any sense. Were you making that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to use `this.local.local_email` (and password) in your save function. Here's the reasoning:

In your constructor, you have local variables for `local_email` and `local_password` - these are the ones you're accessing in your `save` function; When save is called, it checks the local scope (`save`'s own scope, and since these variables aren't there, it checks the next scope up - the constructor scope.

Now, you also have the returned object, which has `local.local_email` as a property. When the constructor is called, this property is set to `undefined` (if I'm following the logic correctly). When it's set later, that change *only happens on the property on that object*. It isn't reflected back to the constructor's local `local_email`.

So, your functions are accessing a local variable, while you're setting a new value on the property of an object.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work - maybe I misunderstood - but I had a thought that I was mixing too JS OO styles and switched to an all-this class definition, which worked. Code below.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you basically implemented my method (using `this`), though in a slightly different way - by setting an explicit reference to `this`. Removing the local variables was definitely a good decision, as it makes things a whole lot clearer. Well done.

Comment: Just to state personal preference: I usually avoid the constructor pattern. It's kind of a strange one, as there aren't (yet) any real "classes" in JS.

Comment: I realized after posting my answer that I had basically implemented your answer without fully understanding your answer until I had done so. :)

Comment: Sometimes you have to *do* to *learn*. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote it this way and it appeared to work, but I am not entire sure why other than to say that I think in the previous example I was mixing different styles of doing JS OO:

```
var User=new require('./models').User;
var user=new User();

user.findUserById('1', function(err, user) {console.log(user)});


var newUser            = new User();

// set the user's local credentials
newUser.local_email    = 'simon@infoqual.net';
newUser.local_password = newUser.generateHash('hello');

// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    console.log(newUser);

});
```

This calls:

```
exports.User = User;

function User() {
    var user=this;
    user.user_uuid=null;
    user.local_email=null;
    user.local_password=null;
    user.generateHash=function (password) {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
    }
    user.validPassword=function (password, password_compare) {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, password_compare);
    }
    user.findUserByEmail=function (email, callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE local_email=$1 LIMIT 1", [email], function (error, result) {
            //var user = this.User;
            if (!error) {
                if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                    user.local_email = result.rows[0].email;
                    user.user_uuid = result.rows[0].user_uuid;

                    //load rest of user obj
                    callback(error, user.user_uuid);
                }


            }
            callback(error, null);

        });


    }

    user.findUserById=function (id, callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uuid='' || $1 LIMIT 1", [id], function (error, result) {
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                //update
                user.user_uuid = result.rows[0].user_uuid;
                user.local_email = result.rows[0].local_email;
                user.local_password = result.rows[0].local_password;
                callback(null, user.user_uuid);
            } else {
                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
    }

    user.save=function (callback) {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uuid='' || $1", [user.user_uuid], function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw error;
            if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                //update
                conn.query("UPDATE users SET local_email=$1, local_password=$2 WHERE user_uuid=$3", [user.local_email, user.local_password, user.user_uuid], function (error, result) {
                    if (error) throw error;

                    callback(error);
                })
            } else {
                //insert
                user.user_uuid=require('node-uuid').v1();
                conn.query("INSERT INTO users (user_uuid, local_email, local_password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", [user.user_uuid, user.local_email, user.local_password], function (error, result) {
                    if (error) throw error;

                    callback(error);
                })
            }
        })
    }
};
```